# CakePHP: Missing Behavior error only happens in production

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My code runs fine with no errors on my local dev server running PHP v5.3.15 but when I upload it to my server (CentOS) running PHP v5.3.26 I get the following "missing behavior" errors:
[image]

Comment: Are you using windows locally? Mind your casing (Containable, not containable).

Comment: @mark No I'm on Linux/apache on both.

Comment: It was the "C" in "containable"! If you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Woops. As you can see, I failed to correctly capitalize 'Containable' in the $actsAs in the model.

Very interesting that this wasn't a problem on my local. Must be a PHP config setting or something.

Comment: Windows tolerates case variation in file names but Linux doesn't. I guess cake was looking for containableBehavior.php instead of ContainableBehavior.php, in windows both name files would work, in linux, only the one with the right case.